# Setup errorformat for multi line error message produces by ghcide

Tags: vim, errorformat

I'm trying to [setup](https://github.com/begriffs/haskell-vim-now/pull/297) `errorformat` for [ghcide](https://github.com/digital-asset/ghcide), which produces following output.

```
ghcide version: 0.0.4 (GHC: 8.6.5)
Ghcide setup tester in /opt/devel/haskell/haskell-vim-now.
Report bugs at https://github.com/digital-asset/ghcide/issues

Step 1/6: Finding files to test in /opt/devel/haskell/haskell-vim-now
Found 1 files

Step 2/6: Looking for hie.yaml files that control setup
Found 1 cradle

Step 3/6, Cradle 1/1: Implicit cradle for /opt/devel/haskell/haskell-vim-now
Cradle {cradleRootDir = "/opt/devel/haskell/haskell-vim-now", cradleOptsProg = CradleAction: default}

Step 4/6, Cradle 1/1: Loading GHC Session

Step 5/6: Initializing the IDE

Step 6/6: Type checking the files
File:     foo.hs
Range:    1:4-1:5
Source:   typecheck
Severity: DsError
Message: 
  ESC[0;91mfoo.hs:1:5: error:
  • No instance for (Num String) arising from the literal ‘5’
  • In the expression: 5
  In an equation for ‘x’: x = 5ESC[0m
Completed (1 file worked, 0 files failed)
```

With following `~/.vim/compiler/ghcide.vim`:

```
CompilerSet  errorformat=%-Gghcide\ %s
CompilerSet  errorformat+=%-GReport\ bugs\ at\ %s
CompilerSet  errorformat+=%-GStep\ %s
CompilerSet  errorformat+=%-GFound\ %s
CompilerSet  errorformat+=%-GCradle\ %s
CompilerSet  errorformat+=%-GRange:\ %s
CompilerSet  errorformat+=%-GFile:\ %s
CompilerSet  errorformat+=%-GSource:\ %s
CompilerSet  errorformat+=%-GSeverity:\ %s
CompilerSet  errorformat+=%-GCompleted\ %s
" exclude empty or whitespace-only lines
CompilerSet  errorformat+=%-G\\s%#
CompilerSet  errorformat+=%E!\ Message:%>%trror%m
setlocal makeprg=ghcide\ %
```

Quickfix buffer shows only remaining four lines:

```
:clist                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 1: Message:-                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 2:   ^[[0;91mfoo.hs:1:5: error:                                                                                                                                                                                   
 3:   • No instance for (Num String) arising from the literal ‘5’                                                                                                                                                  
 4:   • In the expression: 5
```

Since I couldn't figure out by my self how aforementioned multi line message could be mapped into single `clist` entry, I'm looking for help.

Comment: Try this: https://0x0.st/zIaj.txt

Comment: @user938271 thank you so much! It works! Would you put it into an answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
CompilerSet errorformat=%-Gghcide\ %s
CompilerSet errorformat+=%-GReport\ bugs\ at\ %s
CompilerSet errorformat+=%-GStep\ %s
CompilerSet errorformat+=%-GFound\ %s
CompilerSet errorformat+=%-GCradle\ %s
CompilerSet errorformat+=%-GRange:\ %s
CompilerSet errorformat+=%-GFile:\ %s
CompilerSet errorformat+=%-GSource:\ %s
CompilerSet errorformat+=%-GSeverity:\ %s
CompilerSet errorformat+=%-GCompleted\ %s
" exclude empty or whitespace-only lines
CompilerSet errorformat+=%-G\\s%#
CompilerSet errorformat+=%EMessage:%\\s%#%>
CompilerSet errorformat+=%C%\\s%#ESC[%\\d%#;%\\d%#m%f:%l:%c:%m
CompilerSet errorformat+=%C%m
CompilerSet errorformat+=%ZCompleted%m
```

The difference compared to your original code is in the last 4 lines:

```
CompilerSet errorformat+=%EMessage:%\\s%#%>
CompilerSet errorformat+=%C%\\s%#ESC[%\\d%#;%\\d%#m%f:%l:%c:%m
CompilerSet errorformat+=%C%m
CompilerSet errorformat+=%ZCompleted%m
```

Originally, you used this:

```
CompilerSet  errorformat+=%E!\ Message:%>%trror%m
```

But in the compiler output you provided, the `Message:` line does not begin with a bang and a space, so I think it should be removed.

Besides, `%E` already sets the type of the entry to `error`, so `%t` is not necessary.
And there is no message on the line (the message is on the next lines), so you don't need `%m`.
Finally, in the output, there is a trailing whitespace, so you need `%\\s%#`.

All in all this gives:

```
CompilerSet errorformat+=%EMessage:%\\s%#%>
```

But you still need to extract the filename and the line/column position, which you can get with resp. `%f`, `%l` and `%c`:

```
CompilerSet errorformat+=%C%\\s%#ESC[%\\d%#;%\\d%#m%f:%l:%c:%m
```

Note that the format begins with `%C` which tells Vim that it matches the continuation of a multi-line message (see `:h errorformat-multi-line`).

Finally, I think you want the rest of the message, until the `Completed` line, which you can get with:

```
CompilerSet errorformat+=%C%m
CompilerSet errorformat+=%ZCompleted%m
```